# Need some Regex assistance

Tags: c#, regex

So I have this string for input and regex

```cs
string regs = "CREATE PROCEDURE TTTTT.TTTTTTTTT @idVal INT = null, @idVal2 INT, @DecimalVal Decimal(20,2) = null, @NumberVal Numeric(20) = null, @StringVal VarChar(80) = NULL AS";
var result = Regex.Matches(regs, @"\s*(?<parameterdeclaration>@.*?)\s*(.*?=.*?)\s*(,|\bAS\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

which I want to split up in an array as follows:

```
@idVal INT = null, 
@idVal2 INT, 
@DecimalVal Decimal(20,2) = null, 
@NumberVal Numeric(20) = null, 
@StringVal VarChar(80) = NULL AS
```

I have this regex :

```
@"\s*(?<parameterdeclaration>@.*?)\s*([^(\d,\d)],|\bAS\b)"
```

which works as should, but I want to also look at the equals sign ‘=’

So now I have this:

```
@"\s*(?<parameterdeclaration>@.*?)\s*(.*?=.*?)\s*(,|\bAS\b)"
```

But this ends up stringing these two together: `@idVal2 INT, @DecimalVal Decimal(20,2) = null,`

Does any one have an idea how to tell it to first look for **‘=’** followed by **comma** or **AS** and if not found then go for just **comma**
I can’t use @ sign as an end indicator cause the name could still actually contain a @ sign

And I can't say just equals followed by comma OR just comma, because then this field will be cut off @DecimalVal Decimal(20,

So I need it to be if equals followed by comma\AS else comma\AS

Comment: Clarify please. I feel like english is not a language you are very fluent in and some example results of what you mean by "but I want to also look to the equals sign ‘=’" would greatly clarify your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead to assert that the matched characters must be followed by a space or end of the line anchor.

```
(@.*?)(?:,|AS)(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kG1cW9/3)

```
string regs = "CREATE PROCEDURE TTTTT.TTTTTTTTT @idVal INT = null, @idVal2 INT, @DecimalVal Decimal(20,2) = null, @NumberVal Numeric(20) = null, @StringVal VarChar(80) = NULL AS";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(@.*?)(?:,|AS)(?=\s|$)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(regs))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lSTffs)

Comment: or if OP wants "cleaner" result: pattern = (@.*?)(?:,|AS)(?=\s|$) Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);

Comment: yep, capturing the `@` part will help him also to get first part.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TTTTT\.TTTTTTTTT\s*|,\s+
```

or

```
^(.*?)(?=@)|,\s+
```

Try this.Replace with `\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hS3dT7/7

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "CREATE PROCEDURE TTTTT.TTTTTTTTT @idVal INT = null, @idVal2 INT, @DecimalVal Decimal(20,2) = null, @NumberVal Numeric(20) = null, @StringVal VarChar(80) = NULL AS";

string pattern = "@";
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
bool skipfirst = false;

foreach (string match in substrings)
{
     if (skipfirst) Console.WriteLine("'@{0}'", match);
     skipfirst = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a nested OR, like this:

```
\s*(?<parameterdeclaration>@[^\s]+)\s*(.+)((=.+)\s*(,|\bAS\b)|,)
```

I also changed the parameterdeclaration to include the full variable name, as I assumed that's what you wanted.